# Using Arc node and align euler to vector with object - geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to use **arc** to align an instance object **using geometry nodes**.  However it seems to be off.

**Note: I'm trying to use the Arc Node since the angles I will be using won't be whole numbers example 45.34 to 137.54, 173.5 to 243.54, 54.3 to 99.34)**

I'm trying to get something like this using geometry nodes:

[image: img1]

But when I look at it from the top it's off (see red arrow):

[image: img2]

Node Group:

[image: img3]

Comment: Why *Index < 0.8*?

Comment: No reason, the threshold could be 1, I was just trying different things to see if it effected it.  It deletes the extra / overlapping indexed object if threshold is set to 0.

Comment: And a circle instead of an arc would not be an alternative for you here? ...only because the angle runs from $0°$ to $360°$

Comment: I'm using specific angles 135.4, 178.2  not really whole numbers hence using the arc. Example going from 123.34 to 137.54

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the normals of the first and last point do not point in the direction you would expect.

In contrast to all other points, these are turned slightly outwards, because no interpolation between two points takes place here.

Therefore you could simply recalculate the normals:

[image]

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>

Comment: Thanks!!! that one confused me a bit.